# blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame Using the same domain

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome

Hi I am having a problem with this message.

the url from my MAIN page is:

```
page1.mydomain.com/page1.html
```

this page have a Iframe to:

```
frame.mydomain.com/iframe.html
```

and from the main page I open a window from a another page like that:

```
mywindow = window.open("http://page1.mydomain.com/page3.html", 'page3', 'status=1,height=768,width=1280,scrollbars=1');
```

all the 3 pages have set the javascript:

```
document.domain = "mydomain.com";
```

I can interact from the main page to the iframe without a problem.
I only have problem to access the window.open properties.

Like:

```
mywindow.document.getElementById("something")
```

I got that error message.

```
blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame
```

if I try from the page3:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("somethingPage1")
```

I got the same error:

```
blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame
```

Why I can interact with the iframe and can't interact with the window.open and the window.opener ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but this might happen because your iframes/frames are not loaded from the same domain, host, port.  

Here are some resources that might help you:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes

If you have more details, let me know.

Comment: Hi. I did not have problem with iframe. The problem is with popup window. Both are from the same domain/port. In fact the file is in the same directory. As I do not found any solution I am using postMessage...

Comment: Directory does not matter but as far as I remember, even if you set document.domain, you cannot interact with/from pages that are served from subdomains of the main domain. The part with the same directory(path) is irrelevant, so you can have whatever nesting you want. Share some code, on jsbin or jsfiddle or a gist on github and we'll figure it out.

Comment: It doesn't *sound* like both page1 and page3 have set the same `document.domain`. Make sure that *at the time you make the access* the property has been set. This is harder than it sounds because the documents can all take a while to load and run the script that sets `document.domain`. For example if you `window.open` and then immediately access `mywindow.document.something` there is almost no chance that it will be accessible yet. Cross-window scripting is tedious, `window.postMessage` is easier in many cases.

Answer (score -1):

In my case domain names were different and I solved it by replacing client's domain with the parent's domain name. You can try that if domain name is not matter in child(popup) windows.
What you are trying to access window.opener.document.getElementById() won't work.
It will raise security error as you posted. Best way to do is make both the URLs under the same Domain Name if it's possible. Or just for the development you can install extension
"Allow-Control-Allow-Origin:" in Chrome it will work.